# Prove the ternary representation of there natural numbers is not a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Choose some set in the natural numbers such that the language formed by the set under binary representation is a regular language, but is not regular under any other language formed by some base. Prove this using the pumping lemma.

I chose the set $S = \{2^i|i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. It is quite easy to prove this is a regular language under binary representation, but how would you prove that this is not regular under some other base (ie. ternary, quaternary, etc.) using the pumping lemma?

Comment: The pumping lemma is used to prove a language is not regular, while you want to prove the language is regular.

Comment: Are there no restrictions at all on $S$ aside from being some subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the question, after reading it again I have found that it is asking to choose some set S such that there is some base n for which the representation of S is regular and another base for which S representation is not regular. And we must prove it.

Comment: Given the misinterpretation, it would be a good idea (for archival reasons at least) to edit your question to reflect the intended changes.

Comment: The edits have been made, thank you for the insight.

Comment: Answered on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/proving-the-set-of-powers-of-2-over-ternary-alphabet-to-be-non-regular/45968#45968.